# Can REST be used to "call" operations on business objects?

Tags: rest

I have a new project coming up, and am intruiged by REST.  However, it seems to have a very limited interface.  Does REST support object-specific interactions, or is it limited to simple CRUD?

Example:
A school management app has Student objects.  It should be able to:

```
RegisterNewStudent (some data)
```

Each student object should handle business operations:

```
Student.FixName(name data)
Student.ChangeSchool(school data)
Student.Graduate(classrank data)
Student.ChangePassword(password data)
```

I've been implementing CQRS with message queues where each of these things would be a separate Command.  However, in REST it appears I'd be limited to:

```
PUT Student (all data about student)
POST Student/id (update student record with any/all fields changed)
DELETE Student/id
```

Am I missing something here?  Where would lifecycle/statechange logic be implemented in a RESTful solution?  Changing a Student's School enrollment involves different logic (and possibly different permissions) than changing her name.  Would I have to let the client post an "update" of any/all fields and then have to infer what operations they intend?

//Edit:

Is this the sort of thing I'm struggling toward:

```
PUT /Students {data about new student}
POST /Students/314/School {data about different school}
POST /Students/314/Name {data to fix name, ie add middle name}
POST /Students/314/Password {data for new password}
```

etc?

Comment: Each of the example operations you posted is an update operation on some property of the resource.  Why do you think CRUD isn't enough for that?

Comment: Registering a new student creates a new *Registration* of a Student, in which CRUD operations actually make perfect sense, if you operate on the registration records and not the Student records (directly).

Comment: What about intent?  When I want to change a Student's school, do I really need to send their Name/Status/Password/Birthdate/Gender?  Or can individual properties be targeted directly for CRUD operations in REST?

Comment: WRONG: `POST /Students/314/School {data about different school}`  BETTER: `method=POST, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, content-length=LENGTH_OF_MY_JSON_STRING data=MY_JSON_STRING`  Your client sends the JSON (as a "POST" method), your server reads the JSON (as it would any other payload) and responds accordingly (perhaps with a return JSON string, perhaps simply an "OK" HTTP status).

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Can REST be used to “call” operations on business objects?

A: Yes, absolutely yes.

Just as you can invoke any operation on any servlet with GET or PUT, you can also invoke any operation in a REST-ful web service.

Including, but not limited to, CRUD operations :)

Comment: Is it acceptable to nest operations to enable targeted updates?  Like `post /Students/{id}/Name {NameData}` ?

Comment: Your application shouldn't be dealing directly with HTTP grunge like "POST", "GET", URLs or form variables.  Pick a language (Java, C#, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc etc) and find a good library for the language.  Your "operations" and data will be defined in XML or (better!) in JSON.  At that point, you can pretty much do anything you want :)

Comment: @smalltowndev It is okay as long as the student resource contains a link like { href: '/students/123/name', rel='update name' }.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create several webservices to do what you want, but if I take one example of yours:

```
Student.ChangePassword(password data)
```

And have a POST request `/ChangePassword/{student_id}/{password}`

then your only trick is to ensure who can call this function.  Do you use a session cookie to control access, or have them pass in a username/password then a new password?

You will find that POST and PUT will be useful as these aren't logged in the webserver log file.

Comment: @YauheniSivukha - If you use PUT or POST it doesn't go into web server log files so it is safe to do.  GET would be a really bad idea.